# Expression<TDelegate>.Compile and Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, expression-trees

When I compile an expression into executable code and get the delegate - does the code get garbage collected when no more references to this delegate exist?

Is there any documentation on this? Because I didn't find anything useful in the MSDN.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the code can be garbage collected. When you call Compile on an Expression of T, the code is compiled into a [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx), and those are eligible for garbage collection.

Indeed it's not indicated on the MSDN, but you can have a look at the implementation of Expression<T>.Compile in the DLR, which is what .net 4.0 ships:

http://dlr.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54115#990638

Although the implementation of the compiler was different in .net 3.5, DynamicMethods were still used (source: myself, I implemented System.Linq.Expressions in Mono).

The case where compiled expression trees are not collectible, is when you use [Expression<T>CompileToMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728224.aspx), and that you pass a MethodBuilder from an AssemblyBuilder which was not created with the [RunAndCollect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess.aspx) flag.

Comment: Is using DynamicMethod enough? According to the link provided by Eric, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx, the assembly needs to be created with a special flag. In reflector I can see that the method DynamicMethod.GetDynamicMethodsModule() does not create an assembly with RunAndCollect but only with Run.

Comment: Yes, a DynamicMethod is enough, and that's indicated in the MSDN. DynamicMethods have special handling in the CLR, and are indeed collectible.

Comment: Yes, I can see it now in the documentation of the DynamicMethod class. Thanks :)

Comment: My understanding too.  This is strange, I wonder what the point of 'collectable assemblies' is then.

Comment: DynamicMethod is from .net 2.0, where RunAndCollect didn't exist. They have special handling in the runtime, and anonymous one are bound to a new module. RunAndCollect assemblies are new in .net 4.0, and the scope if obviously much broader than simple methods.